# How extract compound name from an string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
structure            dose volume
CEREBRO 0.0 0.0      nan  nan
CEREBRO 10.0 100.0   nan  nan
TRONCO 0.0 0.0       nan  nan
TRONCO 5.0 100       nan  nan
OLHO DIR 0.0 0.0     nan  nan
OLHO DIR 8.0 100.0   nan  nan
```

I have tried to extract the second value of first column to dose and the third value to volume.

```
# fixing columns data
df['dose'] = df['structure_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1])
df['volume'] = df['structure_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])
df['structure_name'] = df['structure_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0]) `
```

It's works for single structure name, but with OLHO DIR, p. ex., the second value is DIR and I have a problem with my dataset.

How could I fix this?

Thanks

```
structure            dose volume
CEREBRO 0.0 0.0      nan  nan
CEREBRO 10.0 100.0   nan  nan
TRONCO 0.0 0.0       nan  nan
TRONCO 5.0 100       nan  nan
OLHO DIR 0.0 0.0     nan  nan
OLHO DIR 8.0 100.0   nan  nan

structure            dose volume
CEREBRO              0.0  0.0
CEREBRO              10.0  100.0
TRONCO               0.0   0.0     
TRONCO               5.0   100      
OLHO                 DIR   0.0     
OLHO                 DIR  8.0 

structure            dose volume
CEREBRO              0.0  0.0
CEREBRO              10.0  100.0
TRONCO               0.0   0.0     
TRONCO               5.0   100      
OLHO DIR             0.0    0.0 
OLHO DIR             8.0    100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
data = [
    ['CEREBRO 0.0 0.0', float('nan'), float('nan')],
    ['CEREBRO 10.0 100.0', float('nan'), float('nan')],
    ['TRONCO 0.0 0.0', float('nan'), float('nan')],
    ['TRONCO 5.0 100.0', float('nan'), float('nan')],
    ['OLHO DIR 0.0 0.0', float('nan'), float('nan')],
    ['OLHO DIR 8.0 100.0', float('nan'), float('nan')]
]
columns = ['structure', 'dose', 'volume']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
print('---------------')
pattern = r'^([a-z ]+?)\s([\d\.]+)\s([\d\.]+)$'
df[columns] = df['structure'].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(df)
```

```
            structure  dose  volume                                                                 
0     CEREBRO 0.0 0.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
1  CEREBRO 10.0 100.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
2      TRONCO 0.0 0.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
3    TRONCO 5.0 100.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
4    OLHO DIR 0.0 0.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
5  OLHO DIR 8.0 100.0   NaN     NaN                                                                 
---------------                                                                                     
  structure  dose volume                                                                            
0   CEREBRO   0.0    0.0                                                                            
1   CEREBRO  10.0  100.0                                                                            
2    TRONCO   0.0    0.0                                                                            
3    TRONCO   5.0  100.0                                                                            
4  OLHO DIR   0.0    0.0                                                                            
5  OLHO DIR   8.0  100.0
```

Comment: You probably need `A-Z` in the regex instead of `a-z`...or better yet do both for more flexibility

Comment: `flags=re.IGNORECASE` means both.

Comment: I missed that detail. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other input formats to account for, you could also split the strings from right to left using `str.rsplit`, setting it to split no more than 2 times and setting `expand=True` to get a dataframe as output.

Complete snippet:

```py
from numpy import nan

# set up data
df = pd.DataFrame({"structure": ['CEREBRO 0.0 0.0',
                                 'CEREBRO 10.0 100.0',
                                 'TRONCO 0.0 0.0',
                                 'TRONCO 5.0 100.0',
                                 'OLHO DIR 0.0 0.0',
                                 'OLHO DIR 8.0 100.0'], 
                   "dose": nan,
                   "volume": nan})


df[["structure", "dose", "volume"]] = df["structure"].str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True)
```

Result:

```py
  structure  dose volume
0   CEREBRO   0.0    0.0
1   CEREBRO  10.0  100.0
2    TRONCO   0.0    0.0
3    TRONCO   5.0  100.0
4  OLHO DIR   0.0    0.0
5  OLHO DIR   8.0  100.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Noticing there could be space in the first str field and the delimiter is also space. Thx @code-apprentice for calling that out.

So, to avoid duplicated solutions using regexp, I modified my previous answer into this:

```py
columns = ['structure', 'dose', 'volume']
col_to_split = 'structure'

def parse(x):
    xs = str(x[col_to_split]).split(' ')
    return [" ".join(xs[:-2])] + xs[-2:]

df[columns] = df[[col_to_split]].apply(parse, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Based on the given example data, this solution assumes:

1. there are only 3 fields and the last two fields are numeric and will not contain space
2. the first field is str and can contain space

Comment: The problem is that the first "column" might have spaces in it, so simply splitting on a space won't solve the problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you are right! Thx for reminding! To avoid duplicated answers (not using regexp) I’ll then modify my answer based on the assumption that the last two columns are numeric.

Comment: I recommend you use actual values instead of place holders such as `'col_to_split` and `'the delemiter'`. Also, will this work correctly for all rows whether or not there is a space in the data for the first column? I think you are assuming there are only 3 columns in the data. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it will work for all row whether there is a space in first field or not. Based on the data provided, there are only 3 columns.

Comment: It would help if you add this assumption to your answer to make it clear.

Comment: It’s not assumption. It’s a description on the example data. BTW, the other answer also doesn’t have the same underlying “assumption”. Do you also consider it unclear?

Comment: Maybe "assumption" is the wrong word. The OP shows three columns that are relevant to their question but doesn't explicitly state that the complete dataset they are working with has only three columns. It's not difficult to imagine that the data shown in the question is a subset of a bigger dataset, most of which is irrelevant to the current question. So my suggestion is to make it clear that your answer will only work if the data shown here represents the full dataset and isn't a subset of a larger dataset. Thanks for editing your question to clarify the assumptions.

Comment: Ok. Then the regular expression solution will also only work properly when there are only 3 fields. Could you please be equally kind to remind him or even the question author about that? Thx for your heart and dedication for this community

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps I'm being too strict on your answer. It took a bit of thinking about it to see how it solves the problem.

Comment: On a different topic...I just noticed you have 2 `return`s. I think you need to remove the second one, right?